# Need help adding MouseListener to 2d array of JPanels

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, mouselistener

so I'm working on a game, the specifics of which don't matter much, but I'm using a board made with an 11x11 2d array of JPanels, then using JLabels as "pieces". I'd like to add a MouseListener to the panels, ex: When panels[10][5] is clicked; panels[10][5].add(redCircle). My issue is just a lack of knowledge about the syntax and use of mouselisteners in general, as my teacher doesn't teach much and I've been having a bit of trouble following online examples. I just need general help with the creation and implementation of such listeners, and any other opinions about my code are highly valued, as this is my first real program and I'm not very good at it.

Here's what I have now:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{ 
    private JPanel[][] panels = new JPanel[11][11];
    private JPanel tilePanel;
    private JLabel blackSquare;
    private JLabel blackCircle;
    private JLabel blackTriangle;
    private JLabel redSquare;
    private JLabel redCircle;
    private JLabel redTriangle;
    private int sideLength;

public GameFrame()
{
    setSize(1000,750);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    sideLength = 11;

    tilePanel = new JPanel();
    tilePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(sideLength,sideLength));

    Color darkBlue = new Color(31,62,148);
    Color darkGray = new Color(107,107,107);

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {           
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
         {                 
             panels[i][j] = new JPanel();
             if (i%2 == j%2)
             {
                 panels[i][j].setBackground(darkGray);   
             }
             else
             {
                 panels[i][j].setBackground(darkBlue);
             } 
             panels[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
             tilePanel.add(panels[i][j]);
         }           
    }        

    blackTriangle = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("blackTriangleUp.fw.png"));
    blackSquare = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("blackSquare.fw.png"));
    blackCircle = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("blackCircle.fw.png"));
    redTriangle = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("redTriangleUp.fw.png"));
    redSquare = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("redSquare.fw.png"));
    redCircle = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("redCircle.fw.png"));

    panels[0][0].add(blackTriangle);
    panels[1][1].add(blackSquare);
    panels[2][2].add(blackCircle);
    panels[3][3].add(redTriangle);
    panels[4][4].add(redSquare);
    panels[5][5].add(redCircle);

    add(tilePanel);
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `"My issue is just a lack of knowledge about the syntax and use of mouselisteners in general, as my teacher doesn't teach much and I've been having a bit of trouble following online examples."` -- Your current code does not show your first best attempt. For best help you should start with those tutorials and at least try to implement a MouseListener first, and then if it doesn't work, show us your attempt. Also you haven't mentioned anything about just what confuses you.

Comment: For instance, you could add a MouseListener to the JPanels in the for loop where they are created.... why not try that and see what happens,... you've absolutely nothing to lose and all to gain in the attempt.

Comment: That would be my issue, I don't know how to add a MouseListener to the JPanels.

Comment: *"I don't know how to add a MouseListener to the JPanel"* - Then I suggest you start with [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: One of the key skills you'll need to move ahead is to be willing to at least try something, anything. If you can't do that, you're sunk.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning how to use search engines before saying you don't know how to do something. Part of programming is learning how to problem solve. But here is an idea on how you can get started with adding a mouse listener to a panel.

```
panels[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
        System.out.println(me); 
      } 
    });
```